# arg can't be coerced to java.util.List? Could any one tell me whats wrong in my code please?

Tags: java, python, jython, grinder

```
myDict = {'itemkey1':'itemvalue1', 'itemkey2':'itemkey2','itemkey3':'itemvalue3','itemkey4':'itemvalue4'};

event = portTest.event(myDict);
```

I am getting the following error

`Aborted run: Jython exception: TypeError:arg can't be coerced to java.util.List`

`myDict` is the array of key values.

i hope i am passing the correct syntax in `myDict` for `keyvalue[]` datalist as it just got key value pair.

```
public Response event(KeyValue[] dataList)
```

I am calling the event function in java from jython script using grinder tool.

Comment: `myDict` is a python dictionary, not a list. What kind of values should `KeyValue` contain?

Comment: KeyValue should contain String key and String val; which is an Array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to turn your dictionary into a series of keys and values:

```
def chainDict(mapping):
    items = []
    for item in mapping.iteritems():
        items.extend(item)
    return items

event = portTest.event(chainDict(myDict))
```

This'll pass a list of `[keyFoo, valueFoo keyBar, valueBar]` to the `event` method, where keys and values are paired but in arbitrary order.

If you don't have an `itertools` module available, `chain` can be defined as:

Comment: net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: ImportError: no
module named itertools

Comment: Thank you for your reply but doesn't it import work in jython ?

Comment: `from net.grinder.script.Grinder import grinder
 from net.grinder.script import Test
 from java.lang import System
 import time
import random
def chain(*iterables):
    for it in iterables:
        for element in it:
            yield element

def userjourney():
 time.sleep(8)
 myDict = {'itemkey1':'itemvalue1', 'itemkey2':'itemkey2','itemkey3':'itemvalue3','itemkey4':'itemvalue4'}
 grinder.logger.info("myDict '%s'" %myDict)
 event = portTest.Event(list(chain(*MyDict.iteritems())))

class TestRunner:
    def __call__(self):
     userjourney()`

Comment: @Shashank: Sure, but does it work? If not, what is your error?

Comment: net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: SyntaxError: ('invalid syntax') line no: where iam starting the function def chain(*iterables): and yield element (no code object) at line 0 this is the error iam getting

Comment: @Shashank: Right, there is more syntax missing than I thought. Updated answer to fit.

Comment: thank you, that has fixed that problem but i got a new error which says:   ERROR SHASHANK-PC-0 thread-1 [ run-0 ]: Aborted run: Jython exception: NameError: MyDict [calling TestRunner]
net.grinder.scriptengine.jython.JythonScriptExecutionException: NameError: MyDict
 File "C:\event.py", line 56, in userjourney
 File "C:\event.py", line 99, in __call__

Comment: @Shashank: Small typo on my part (`myDict` vs. `MyDict`), corrected.

Comment: @Martijin, I have got a small doubt , does this still pass the list in arbitrary order because  my values will be something like: key1 = 1 which corresponds to value1 = item1. if it is in arbitrary it would be like key 1 corresponds to value 2 which is another value for the that key. Could you please clarify me this. Thank you

Comment: @Shashank: The key and value will be grouped, the order of the *groups* is arbitrary. So it could be `[key1, value1, key2, value2]` *or* it could be `[key2, value2, key1, value1]`. The key and value stay together.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly pass `myDict.items()` instead of `myDict` for `KeyValue` pairs, `myDict.keys()` for the keys, or `myDict.values()` for err, the values...

Comment: but i need to pass both key & value array